# Android menu buttons not responding

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have written the code to create an Android menu but the buttons don't carry out the actions when pressed. I can't seem to figure out the problem.

```
   @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.option_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

public boolean onOptionsItemsSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.scan:
        //Launch DeviceListActivity to see devices and scan
        Intent serverIntent = new Intent(this, DeviceListActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(serverIntent, REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE);
        System.out.println("Scan Pressed!");
        return true;
    case R.id.discoverable:
        //ensure device is discoverable
        ensureDiscoverable();
        System.out.println("Discoverable Pressed!");
        return true;            
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

I get this logcat error:

12-28 10:19:05.769: W/KeyCharacterMap(1876): Error loading keycharmap file '/system/usr/keychars/qtouch-obp-ts.kcm.bin'. hw.keyboards.131072.devname='qtouch-obp-ts'
12-28 10:19:05.769: W/KeyCharacterMap(1876): Can't open keycharmap file
12-28 10:19:05.769: W/KeyCharacterMap(1876): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin

Comment: Can share more details .. such as  layout , n full code ??

Comment: please  @Override onOptionsItemsSelected method.

Comment: post the logcat, if the problem still remains

Comment: 12-28 10:19:05.769: W/KeyCharacterMap(1876): Error loading keycharmap file '/system/usr/keychars/qtouch-obp-ts.kcm.bin'. hw.keyboards.131072.devname='qtouch-obp-ts'
12-28 10:19:05.769: W/KeyCharacterMap(1876): Can't open keycharmap file
12-28 10:19:05.769: W/KeyCharacterMap(1876): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo. The name of the method is `onOptionsItemSelected()`, not `onOptionsItemsSelected()`. Your method is never being called.

Comment: That's why he isn't using the `@Override` annotation